# URL getting forcefully redirected in gMail

Tags: javascript, html, email, html-email

URL is opening in new page and facing this issue,

> > Redirect Notice  The page you were on is trying to send you to an invalid URL.
>
> If you do not want to visit that page, you can return to the previous
>   page.

HTML

```
<a href="<%= ACTIVELINK %>" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">Click for Activation</a>
```

I have tried `target="_blank"` removing and adding but still getting this.
It is working fine with our email providers but with Gmail getting this,

```
https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&q=http:/LIVEIP:3000/api/v1/auth/verifyEmail/TOKEN&source=gmail&ust=1533110923341000&usg=AFQjCNHXC9iYIPaoe38zB2bAwuax5qrTJg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your LIVEIP address is getting escaped like

```
http:/LIVEIP
```

You can try to set ACTIVELINK's / to 3 times to work as escaped like

```
ACTIVELINK = 'http://LIVEIP'
```

should be (one more / )

```
ACTIVELINK = 'http:///LIVEIP'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the ACTIVELINK value to:

```
ACTIVELINK = 'http:\/\/LIVEIP';
```